# What value is suitable for the action attribute in a form?

Tags: html

I understand that the value of the action attribute is the URL for  the page on the server that will receive the information in the form when it is submitted. However, what URL do I use? Do I need to program a new page using PHP (which I don't know how to use yet as I am learning HTML first) or is there a website that can do this for me? (The book I am using just writes the value as: "http://www.example.com/profile.php" - the .php at the end of this URL gave me the the PHP idea)

```
<form action="WHAT DO I PUT HERE?" method="post">
<p>What's your favorite genre of music?</p>
<textarea name="musician">Who's your favorite artist?</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

If it's information that I would like to see and analyse (for example in an online survey) would the URL be different to if I wanted the user simply to upload their thoughts (like a comments box).

Apologies if this is a fairly basic question but I am new to coding websites. Also, just out of interest what is a good way to learn how to code websites? (i.e any suggestions for good books, websites or suchlike?) Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to input the URL of a server-side program/script/"page" which, when it receives data via POST, will do something with it. Whether you write this yourself or find some existing service or script which already does it is up to you, that's none of HTML's concern.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: rtfm http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: @barakmanos,chiliNUT Please don't recommend and awful site like that. See [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: w3 is terrible, but it does not take a "great" site to explain form submission, and again, was chosen to demonstrate that the top hit from google would have answered OP's question

Comment: @chiliNUT Then please at least don't describe W3Schools as "TFM". The official FM is at http://w3.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms) a good resource for what you're trying to do. There's even a [specific section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) for sending/receiving data.

A protip if you're new to web development: stay away from w3schools. Mozilla is a **much** better resource, cannot stress this enough.

Comment: generally very true, but for something like explaining form submission w3 actually suffices, and it was chosen because it demonstrates that the top hit for a trivial google search of "php form action" would provide the answer without having to post a question on SO

Comment: protip prefix any google search about web development with "mdn" to get the mdn result instead of the w3c result